# Kubernetes traefik through a specific internal IP

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am setting up Kubernetes in a RedHat server in my institution, the server has an internal IP of **10.2.3.4**. I can only view the pod by using kubectl port-forward. e.g

My traefik service has the following:

```
#minikube service list
| kube-system | traefik    | web/80        | http://172.17.0.3:31909 |
|             |            | websecure/443 | http://172.17.0.3:30584 |
|             |            | admin/9001    | http://172.17.0.3:32316 |
|-------------|------------|---------------|-------------------------|
```

Now I can only curl this link

```
 $curl http://172.17.0.3:32316/dashboard/
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Traefik</title><meta charset=utf-8> ........
```

However, if I want to preview the admin dashboard on my browser on 9001 port, the only way I have found yet is though port-forward:

```
kubectl port-forward -n kube-system $(kubectl get pods  --output=name -n kube-system | grep 'traefik') --address 10.2.3.4 9001:9001
```

I tried to set `externalIPs` on service YAML settings but it doesn't work:

```
# Service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: traefik
    release: traefik
  name: traefik
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  externalIPs:
    - 10.2.3.4
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ports:
    - name: web
      nodePort: 31909
      port: 3838
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3838
    - name: admin
      nodePort: 32316
      port: 9001
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9001
  selector:
    app: traefik
    release: traefik
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I know the port-forward should be used in debug mode, I cannot add my own domain since it is restricted in my institution, I wonder if there are settings I should make the kubernete services exposed to **10.2.3.4**?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way to expose your service is

```
kubectl expose deployment *name* --type=LoadBalancer --name=trafik
```

**name** - says deployement name which you should have given in deployment.yaml

I am assuming, you use traefik as Gateway/LoadBalancer here. You can use the same execution for any services to expose internal IP.

Comment: Thanks! But I still don't know how this connects to the IP 10.2.3.4, I'm trying to say I only have this IP that can be accessed from the public/browser.

Comment: It is not safe to use internal IP that is why you need to expose deployment and then access it via externalIP of associated service. You can also add port and targetPort flags to above command. See more: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/source-ip/#source-ip-for-services-with-typeloadbalancer